# Why there is no stack interface in the collection framework?

Tags: java, collections, interface, frameworks, stack

Why there is no stack interface in the collection framework in java?
Java Collection framework provides many interfaces (Set, List, Queue, Deque) and classes (ArrayList, Vector, LinkedList, PriorityQueue, HashSet, LinkedHashSet, TreeSet). So, why not a stack interface?

Comment: While it's true there's no dedicated stack interface that only supports LIFO, the `Deque` interface can function as a stack.

Comment: Set, List, Queue, and Deque all have multiple implementations.  Stack has only one implementation (setting aside the fact that Deque functions as a stack).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Stack` is a legacy class. A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the `Deque` interface and its implementations.

From [java-doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html),

> Deques can also be used as LIFO (Last-In-First-Out) stacks. This
> interface should be used in preference to the legacy Stack class

`Stack` class diagram,[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think because there is already a java.util.Stack class, they couldn't add a stack interface without causing a lot of confusion.